# How to Copy the Error message (Only) from the Error List Window in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

When right click and copy the Error, every column is copied as well, including the lengthy directory. Any idea?

Comment: Why not copy it from the output window, if you need only parts of the error?

Comment: Same here, is there any plugin for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When right clicking you also have 'show columns'.
If you disable some columns it is possible to get only the error-message when you right click and copy.

Comment: This still copies the column header, "Description". It would be nice if they would just add a new context entry for "Copy error description". I want to see all the columns but I only want to copy the text (to supply to ChatGPT or to Google)